# Set and Verify the Retention Value for Change Data Capture

Tags: sql-server, database, cdc, sql-server-2017, change-data-capture

How to set and verify the retention value for CDC?

The retention value refers to the number of days to clean the logs.

The default value is 4320 minutes. I need to change.

Answer (score 2):

To verify:

```
SELECT [retention]
  FROM [msdb].[dbo].[cdc_jobs]
  WHERE [database_id] = DB_ID()
  AND [job_type] = 'cleanup'
```

To set:

```
sp_cdc_change_job @job_type='cleanup', @retention=7200
```